# Downloading large files with cURL?

Tags: php, curl

I'm fairly new to cURL and searched for a good script to download remote files to my server using cURL. What I found was this:

```
<?php
    $url  = 'http://www.example.com/a-large-file.zip';
    $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/downloads/a-large-file.zip';

    $fp = fopen($path, 'w');

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
    fclose($fp);
?>
```

This script was [here](http://www.phpriot.com/articles/download-with-curl-and-php) and it works, to a part. Although in the article, it's stated that this code doesn't have the problem of the php memory limit, **it just downloads exactly 8 MB of the file**, no matter the size of the file.

Does anyone have any idea where this limitation is coming from and how to overcome it?

Comment: Downloading a file has no limit, all your server need bandwidth and free space to store file.

Comment: @WaqarAlamgir, I don't think it's a problem of storage, cause I tried to download several files and all of them stopped at 8 MB. As for the bandwidth, can the server has limit on a single file transfer? If so, then it's a possibility.

Comment: Can you make sure file at http://www.example.com/a-large-file.zip is not 8MB

Comment: @WaqarAlamgir, one of the files I tested the script on was this: http://mirror.cogentco.com/pub/mysql/MySQL-5.6/MySQL-5.6.10-1.el6.src.rpm (32 MB) and I still got the 8 MB part.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found where did the problem come from: The script worked well, but it was the limitation of the server. I hadn't payed attention to their policy which clearly stated that no file larger that 8 MB is allowed to be uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

Could the problem be related to timeout?
Try to add

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 300); // where 300 is number of seconds

Comment: I added the line and still am getting the 8 MB files (even with setting the number to for example 3000). So, I don't think that's the case here.

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the memory_limit in your php.ini. Default was 8M before PHP 5.2.0.

Comment: But I thought this script was writing straight to the file stream and not storing it in the memory and then writing it to the file. Thus solving the problem with php's memory limit.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this at top of your script

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

Comment: Won't this stop the script from downloading anything at all?